# How to get the download attribute from WKWebView?

Tags: macos, download, webkit, wkwebview

Some anchors may have a download attribute with or without a filename specified ([Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)). How do you retrieve this filename within `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like none of the parameters webview and navigationAction do expose the value of the download attribute of the anchor tag clicked.

I solved this by calling **webview.evaluateJavascript()** executing **document.querySelector()** by the href attribute that we received from navigationAction.request.url.absoluteString:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('[href=\"" + navigationAction.request.url.absoluteString + "\"]').download") {(result, error) in

        let fileName = result as? String ?? "FALLBACK DEFAULT NAME.csv"

        ...

    }

}
```